# Is there a way to detect if there was a purchase after SKStoreProductViewController is presented?

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

My app plays songs from the user's music library on their iOS device- it uses SKStoreProductViewController to purchase music and i'm looking to see if there is a way to detect if something was purchased.

I checked the SKStoreProductViewController docs but the method **loadProductWithParameters:completionBlock:** does not include a way to detect if the product presented was purchased.

Is there a way to figure out if the presented product was purchased?

Maybe registering *MPMediaLibrarySyncGenerationDidChangeNotification* would do the trick?

Comment: Some thoughts on this: 1) Apple says that by default duplicate iTunes music purchases will be warned to the user so you might check this in your app and leave the check to iTunes 2) store everything in NSDefault so at least purchased from your app can be checked 3) non-consumable in-app items should be restorable so be prepared to implement restore function too.